# Returning a value from a js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm using the [Query](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#query-and-mutation-components) component of React-Admin version 2.9 and I'm having trouble accessing its returned value. I've looked through github for usage examples, but with no luck thus far. It's an old version of the framework and the Query component appears to now be deprecated.

But I believe my issue may be a more generic one relating to my not fully grasping how to deal with js promises.

My function uses Query to make an api call and it looks like this:

```
const myfunction = (avalue) => 
    <Query type="GET_LIST" resource="student" payload={{ filter: { id: avalue }}}>
        {({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (loading) { return "loading"; }
            if (error) { return "error"; }
            return data.filter( i => i.studentType === 1 ).length
        }}
    </Query>
```

The result of the api call is an Integer value and I believe the above is obtaining it correctly.

Yet when I try to access the return value in this way ...:

```
console.log(myfunction(123));
```

... I don't get the actual value, but instead I get this:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
```

Any idea why the above is getting returned instead of the actual value and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a React component. React components, when executed, return a React element. They are designed to be rendered in JSX, not to be called directly. See https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components for details.

If you want to execute a query in the JS (not JSX) part of a component, in react-admin 2.9 you must use [the `withDataProvider` decorator](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.9/Actions.html#using-the-withdataprovider-decorator).

Here is an example usage:

```
import {
   showNotification,
   UPDATE,
   withDataProvider,
} from 'react-admin';

class ApproveButton extends Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        const { dataProvider, dispatch, record } = this.props;
        const updatedRecord = { ...record, is_approved: true };
        dataProvider(UPDATE, 'comments', { id: record.id, data: updatedRecord })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(showNotification('Comment approved'));
                dispatch(push('/comments'));
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                dispatch(showNotification('Error: comment not approved', 'warning'))
            });
    }

    render() {
        return <Button label="Approve" onClick={this.handleClick} />;
    }
}

ApproveButton.propTypes = {
    dataProvider: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    record: PropTypes.object,
};

export default withDataProvider(ApproveButton)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This helps! And `withDataProvider` can only be used with a class component (and not with functional components), correct?

Comment: no, withDataProvider can be used with both class and function components. If my response is enough to solve your question, please mark it as such!